# Userform only on specific days

Tags: excel, vba

I just want to be able to open my userform only on specific days of the week.
Let's say I want to open it on a Monday, I got a msgbox "You can only use this on Fridays"
And then I can open my userform when it's Friday.

I don't know what I can use : "OnTime", "Weekday" ?

Help me please

Comment: How did you try using `Weekday`?

Comment: You can use the `Workbook_Open`-Event and then check for the Weekday `Weekday(Now, vbMonday)` and then build some logic, which will trigger the userform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your locale has English day-names, invoke the Userform with something like:

```
Sub dural()
    If Format(Now, "dddd") <> "Friday" Then
        MsgBox "only on Fridays"
    Else
        UserForm1.Show
    End If
End Sub
```